# pig script to print dataset conditionally

Tags: apache-pig

we have two datasets: 
Student: This dataset contains name and roll number of students in a class 
Results: This dataset contains roll number and result (Fail or Pass) of students

Write a Pig script to analyse the given datasets and print the student names who have successfully cleared the exam.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

input 1- result.dat file(id, status)
input 2- student.dat file(name,id)

```
re = load 'results.dat' as (id:int,status:chararray); 

st = load 'student.dat' as (name:chararray,id:int); 

join_re_st = join re by $0,st by $1; 

fil = filter join_re_st by $1 != 'fail'; 

result = foreach fil generate $0,$1,$2; 

Dump result;
```